# CSS - Cannot get single li element to reveal div on hover

Tags: css, class, html, menu

I want a drop down log-in box (div class="signin") to appear when a user hovers over the Login part of my Nav bar (li class="menuLogin). However for some reason I am having a lot of trouble achieving this, even though it seems simple.

The log-in box is set as follows:

```
.signin {
...
...
display:none;
}
```

I would then assume if I wanted to make the log-in box visible on hovering I would do the following:

```
#nav > ul > li.menulogin:hover .signin{
    display:block;
}
```

However, this and many variations and I cannot get it to work!

Testing

```
#nav > ul > li.menulogin:hover{
    font-size:20px;
}
```

indeed changed the font size for the nav bar, so this part works. Is it where I say:

```
#nav > ul > li.menulogin:hover .signin{
}
```

where I am going wrong?

Many thanks.

HTML as follows:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="menulogin"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <div class="signin" popup="">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="title"> SIGN IN </div>
        <form method="post" action="www.google.com">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="inputrow"><input type="text" class="box-input" id="usernameInput"

                name="Login" placeholder="Username" /> </div>
            <div class="inputrow"><input type="password" class="box-input" id="passInput"

                name="Password" placeholder="Password" /> </div>
            <div class="row"> <input type="submit" value="ENTER" class="button" />
            </div>
            <div class="row"> <a href="/member/forgotpassword">Forgot
                Password?</a> </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <li><a href="#">En</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">£</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Corporate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS is as follows:

```
#nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 6px 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #1c2d5f;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f3ddaa; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 
    font:16px Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}
#nav ul li {
    float: right; 
}
#nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #e9cb73;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
#nav ul li a:hover{
    display:block;
    color: #f3ddaa;
    background-color: #253775; 
}


#nav > ul > li.menulogin:hover .signin{

display:block;

}

/*LOGIN BOX*/
.signin {
width: 212px;/*width of element*/
right: 0px;/*needed for position*/
top: 37px; /*height of navbar*/
border: solid; /*standard border*/
border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;/*standard border*/
border-color:#f3ddaa;/*standard border*/
position: absolute;/*ignores other elements for position*/
background: #1c2d5f;/*background colour*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px;/*nice shadow effect*/
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px;/*nice shadow effect*/
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), to select the `.signin` element preceding `li.menulogin`:

```
#nav > ul > li.menulogin:hover + .signin {
    display:block;
}
```

[**WORKING EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/P6LEX/)

You were trying to select a `.signin` element that was a child of `li.menulogin`.

Usage of `+` assumes that the elements are adjacent. You would otherwise use the [general sibling combinator, `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), if that wasn't the case.

```
#nav > ul > li.menulogin:hover ~ .signin {
    display:block;
}
```

It's also worth noting that the `.signin` element will disappear if you were to hover over it (as it does in the example above). To solve this, add `display:block` when hovering over it (`.signin:hover`)

```
#nav > ul > li.menulogin:hover + .signin, .signin:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fctR6/)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and a clear and concise explanation of why. Allister Quinn